# Calling select in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Whenever I run this code on raspberry pi, I get this error message for my argument for the ... TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.

```
input = [sys.stdin]
while(1):
        try:
              inputready, _, _ = select.select(input,[],[], 10)   

        except Exception as e:
              print(e); break
```

Comment: __Note__: Don't name your variables the same as [__builtins__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: Which OS are you running and what python version?

Comment: wheezy-raspbian, python 2.7.3

Comment: Oddly enough the code has no faults. http://pastebin.com/7yriM6P7  `Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) - [GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)] on linux2` I'll try on my RPi and VoCore later tonight if no one else answers before that.

Answer (score 0):

All goes as expected:

```
user@raspberrypi ~/src $ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l
user@raspberrypi ~/src $ python --version
Python 2.7.3
user@raspberrypi ~/src $ cat check_select.sh 
import sys,select
input = [sys.stdin]
while(1):
        try:
              inputready, _, _ = select.select(input,[],[], 10)   

        except Exception as e:
              print(e); break 
user@raspberrypi ~/src $ python !$
python check_select.sh
adsfdsf
```

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid \n \l

Python 2.7.3rc2